# Build org-mode documents to specific folder

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have org-mode files in a git repo and don't want to pollute it with with build files. [I probably can't tell git to ignore the built files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130246/conditional-gitignore/41135495#41135495)

Can I tell Emacs to build the files (see linked question for a list) to a specific folder? I'd prefer the built files to be stored in a common location for all org-mode files, not matter where they are on my system because I don't intend to keep them, but if I can specify that they are put into a certain folder relative to the location of the org-mode document, that's fine, too.

I tried building the file via pandoc because you can run bash scripts from Emacs and in a bash script I could (if I could pass the location of the current file as a parameter) just call pandoc and tell it to store the resulting PDF (pandoc doesn't even create the other files) in the folder I want them to be stored in. However, I wasn't able to make the documents look like the ones org-mode builds.

Comment: Possibly http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/make-org-mode-export-to-beamer-keep-temporary-files-out-of-the-current-directory

Comment: @JeanPierre Thank you, that solved my problem! I flagged my quesiton as a duplicate of that quesiton so others coming across mine can find the solution there.